# Updating `scrollPosition` when contents are reordered iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I'm working with the new ScrollView API for iOS 17 and ran into a little snag with the `scrollPosition(id:)` modifier. It works pretty well in a context like this:

```
var items: [Item]
@State var scrollPosition: Item?

ScrollView(.horizontal) {
  HStack(spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
      ItemView(for: item)
        .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
    }
  }
  .scrollTargetLayout()
}
.ignoresSafeArea()
.scrollIndicators(.hidden)
.scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition)
.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
```

Here, we have a full-screen horizontal ScrollView that pages, meaning I can swipe left and right between the full screen pages. On top of that, it will track which `Item` we are currently scrolled to. The snag I've run into has to do with when we change the ordering of `items`. (`Item` can be any `Hashable` here).

Let's say our `items` array looks like this: `[item1, item2, item3, item4]` and we're looking at the first page in our ScrollView, corresponding to `item1`. Then let's say we reorder `items` from elsewhere, such that it looks like this: `[item3, item1, item2, item4]`.

In this case, our `scrollPosition` still maintains `item1` as its value, even though we're now viewing `item3` on the first page. In other words, what we see in the ScrollView, and our `scrollPosition`, are inconsistent.

My question is: when `items` is reordered, how can we have `scrollPosition` update to have the value of the `item` on the page we're viewing. In our example above, `scrollPosition` should update to `item3`.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The root of the issue is, that you make the assumption, that a scroll view takes *full control* over the scroll position. That's not completely correct. In fact, it does not touch the binding `@State scrollPosition` unless, it *actually* scrolls, which it does not do without any command. So, initially when it receives the items, it does not scroll at all.

What you always should keep in mind is, that **views are a function of state**.

That is, you *as well* can control the state with some logic and the view renders it as the state demands. Your logic *can* control the current list of items *and* the item currently in the visible page.

So, what you need to do is, *say* the view *what* it should render through controlling its *whole* state:

> My question is: when items is reordered, how can we have scrollPosition update to have the value of the item on the page we're viewing.

Sounds like a clear requirement. So, you need to implement the logic, see below:

The interesting part is in the action closure of

```
.onChange(of: items, initial: true)
```

it explicitly determines *what* the scroll view should do regarding its scroll position, when its `items` variable changes.
If this logic is *not* what you actually want, just implement it in a way which suits your needs.

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    let items: [Item]
    @State var scrollPosition: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    ItemView(item: item)
                        .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition)
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        .onChange(of: items, initial: true) { oldValue, newValue in
            if let currentItem = scrollPosition,
                  let currentIndex = oldValue.firstIndex(of: currentItem),
                  let newItem = newValue.indices
                      .contains(currentIndex) ? 
                      newValue[currentIndex] :
                      nil
            {
                self.scrollPosition = newItem
            } else {
                // newItem is nil. Choose any other if one exists, 
                // otherwise set it to nil:
                let newScrollPosition = newValue.count > 0 ? 
                                        newValue[0] : 
                                        nil
                if newScrollPosition != self.scrollPosition {
                    self.scrollPosition = newScrollPosition
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Some clarifying notes:**

Somewhere I said: "when its items variable changes"

Actually, `items` is a let constant. So, how is this a variable?

So, here we need to know about the declarative approach. The *actual underlying* view which is associated to this declarative form, *has* a state and it manages this. Part of the state is also the `items` array.

A SwiftUI view is a *means* to change this underlying view. Think of it as a *function* which either *creates* or *modifies an existing* underlying view.

So, as long as the SwiftUI view *identifies* the *same* underlying view, you can use a let constant in a SwiftUI view to *modify* the state of the underlying view.

So, given this explanation, what `onChange()` actually means in this context should become clear: the closure will be called, when the array of items changes, which is part of the state *of the underlying actual view*.

**And another thing**

I would also agree, that the scroll view *should* update its scroll position when its content changes. This would have probably avoided any additional effort. But, alas, as we see, it's not the case. You can debug this, and you will see, that ScrollView will only update the scroll position *after* it actually scrolled.